# I can't print a graph (lines) using GD and perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print this two arrays (@x and @) in a linear graph

```
for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@$rlSeqNames); $i++) {
    my $name1 = $rlSeqNames->[$i];          
    for (my $j=($i+1); $j<scalar(@$rlSeqNames); $j++) {
        my $name2 = $rlSeqNames->[$j];          
        my $ds = $Data->{$name1}->{$name2}->{ds};
        my $dn = $Data->{$name1}->{$name2}->{dn};
        my $ratio = $Data->{$name1}->{$name2}->{ratio};
        my(@x, @y);
        push @x, $name1.$name2 ; 
        push @y, sprintf ("\n%8.2f",$ratio);
        my $graph = GD::Graph::lines->new();
        $graph->set(
            x_label => 'ID',
            y_label => 'Genetic distance (d)',
            title => 'A Simple Proof',);
    my @data = (\@x, \@y);
    print OUT Dumper(\@data);
    my $gd = $graph->plot( \@data );
    $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph ->error;
    my $file = 'proof.png';
    open(my $out, '>', $file)
    or die "Cannot open '$file' for write: $!";
    binmode $out;
    print $out $graph->gd->png;
    close $out;
}
```

}
  }

Dumper (\@data) gives to me the correct values, then, in the graphic, only appear one dot that corresponds to the last element of the @data. Does anybody know what is wrong with this code? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your listing appears to be missing your closing `}` for your loops, but I would say that the problem is that you are making `@x` and `@y` lexical (using `my`) to the inner loop scope.

Move the statement `my (@x,@y)` to the very top of the listing - outside both loops - to make the lexical variables scope over the whole thing as you apparently require.

I presume that `my $graph = GD::Graph::lines->new();` and all lines following it is intended to be outside both loops, despite the confusing indentation and lack of closing `}`.

Comment: Yes, it works now! thank you very much! Im new using perl and sometimes I  don't realize about the simpliest mistakes!